# MATLAB Invalid File Identifier while trying to use fwrite to write to an existing empty text file

Tags: matlab, fopen, identifier

fid2 opens an existing text file which is empty . I want to write a new line to this empty file. The reason I used a+ is because I want to use fid2 again later inside a loop to add lines to the txt file.

```
addpath('home/oa/Desktop/T/K') 
fid2 = fopen( 'r1.txt', 'a+' );

fwrite(fid2,c1);
```

The message that appears is

> Error using fwrite Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a
>   valid file identifier.
>
> Error in coef (line 70)
>       fwrite(fid2,c1);

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
[fid2,m] = fopen( 'r1.txt', 'a+' );
```

then check the content of m

Comment: It says 'Permission Denied' .  Do I have to be root?

Comment: Yes, I do! Thanks a lot!